# Can you play Minecraft Java Edition on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

My son really wants to play the Java Edition of Minecraft. Any tips for playing the Java Edition on Windows 10? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to play Minecraft Java Edition on Windows 10.

Simply go to the official Minecraft website, click on the Get Minecraft button or expand the games menu and select Minecraft, select computer, select PC and finally, select Java Edition. If you already have a Minecraft account, just click download it again.

Comment: Note that the account system for BedrockWin10 and Java are *not linked*, Java has a fee of $35 if you've never purchased it, even if you've purchased Windows 10 before.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 its not $35, its $27

Comment: @Penguin My bad, I'm Canadian. Canada's price is $35.

Comment: Oh sorry, $27 USD and $35 CAD, confusing xd!

Comment: You will also need Java to play Minecraft Java Edition. It sounds obvious but then again the question sounded obvious to me but is apparently not.

Comment: @qwr that was the case with older versions but nowadays Minecraft uses its own JRE. Quote from minecraft.net: "Starting from Minecraft 1.12, Java 8 will be required to run Minecraft. If you don't know whether you have Java 8, don't worry - our installers supply Minecraft with its own version of Java by default.". However, you might still need to install Java if you plan on using Forge or Optifine.

Answer (score 2):

Java Edition, by the nature of Java, runs on any desktop OS. You can download it from [the Minecraft website](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/get-minecraft) by selecting `Computer` -> `PC`. Your purchased copy of the game is associated with the account you sign-in to, meaning you can re-download it as many times as you like on any computer you like

Answer (score -1):

Its possible and Java Edition is designed for PC so you should be able to run it with no problems if you install correctly. Just remember to install the latest version of Java so that the game can work. In some of the other answers you can see how to install it.

Comment: Hi @Smixxand, welcome to Arqade. Do you feel like your answer covers anything that the other answers have missed? Can you highlight this? Or if you think existing answers can be improved, you will be able to comment on them once you get enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but Java does not need to be installed for newer versions, so although this answer does add *something* it is no longer correct.